# Jenkins CI Server filled up disk space

Tags: centos7, jenkins

Today I realized, that my server did not send a logcheck mail, like it should do every night. I logged into my box with ssh and the first commands I typed returned `no disk space left`. The administration panel of my hoster (Virtuozzo power panel) displayed a similar warning, 99% used. This was rather strange, because the box is quite new (6 weeks old) and should have a disk usage of 2% (like it said in the logcheck mail the day before). Using `du -sh` I tried to find the big file, but there was nothing. No files, no big folders.

After reading about a case where bad session handling caused the disk to fill up in a specific constellation with php, I decided to shut down all of my web applications, one after one (php is not installed on my server). My first guess was my Jenkins server and just after I stopped the service, my administration tool showed `2% disk usage` again. So I found the error, but I do not know what caused it. Jenkins was the first thing I installed 6 weeks ago, and there was never a problem until now. I could not see any suspicious access to Jenkins, there were some failed logins by bots in my logs every other day, but I don't this is unusual. I was not able to google this behavior and (of course) am a little worried about it. What can/should I do to prevent it from occuring?

Note that my Jenkins Server currently has one checkin-build and one nightly build, both are small Java-EE applications.

Comment: Could you confirm that now Jenkins has been started again and that he usage is still 2%?

Comment: Confirmed. Started the service, started a build, usage still 2%.

Answer (score -1):

To check the free space as ***Jenkins Job***:

## Parameters

- **`FREE_SPACE`**: Needed free space in *GB*.

## Job

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

free_space="$(df -Ph . | awk 'NR==2 {print $4}')"

if [[ "${free_space}" = *G* ]]; then
  free_space_gb=${x/[^0-9]*/}

  if [[ ${free_space_gb} -lt ${FREE_SPACE} ]]; then
    echo "Warning! Low space: ${free_space}"
    exit 2
  fi
else
  echo "Warning! Unknown: ${free_space}"
  exit 1
fi


echo "Free space: ${free_space}"
```

## Plugins

### Set build description

#### Post-Build Actions

- **Regular expression**: `Free space: (.*)`
- **Description**: `Free space: \1`
- **Regular expression for failed builds**: `Warning! (.*)`
- **Description for failed builds**: `\1`